# Reading DateTime from Database using Delphi and FireDAC

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi, firedac

I'm failing dismally to read a datetime from an SQLite database using Delphi 10.3 and FireDAC.
As the simplest example, I create a sample database using sqlite as follows:

```
.open Test.db
CREATE TABLE "TABLE1" ("Name"VarChar(16), "Time" datetime); 
INSERT INTO Table1 (Name,Time) VALUES("Fred",time('now'));
```

Then

```
select * from Table1
```

gives Fred|16:52:57 as expected.

If I generate a Delphi program with an FDConnection1 and FDQuery1 linked to a datasource and DBgrid it will read "Fred" but not the time. The value returned by FDquery1 asstring is '' and asfloat is 0. 
If I try the FireDAC explorer tool to look at the database it also fails to read the time value but I notice it does read datetimes from some of the example databases so it clearly can work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `MyQuery.FieldByName('Time').AsDateTime`?

Comment: Use `datetime('now')` instead of `time('now')`.

Comment: Btw, browsing this q on SO, it looks almost greyed out for no apparent reason.  Is it just me? I've noticed this a few times over the past couple of months or so.

Comment: @MartynA: Does it happen when you press the J key on your keyboard?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand:  It's only when I'm browsing the list of qs - if I go into it to read the actual q or answer, it displays normally, bbut when I go back to the browse list, the reing-out returns.  The J key doesn't make any difference.  There's another recent quirk of the browser - when a new question is posted and answered (or modified by someone other than the OP) before I've read it, the other person's name is displayed where the OP's would normally be.  After a while, it displays the OP's name instead.

Comment: @MartynA: Yes, I have seen that as well (not the OP's name).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. Yes I've tried that. Delphi returns it as 30/12/1899 which is time zero.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I just used time('now') as an an example piece of data to demonstrate the problem. Using datetime('now')  has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to construct a SQL statement as a string in Delphi code can be a bit error prone.  However, you should find that the following code executes correctly

```
procedure TForm2.btnInsertRowClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  sInsertRow = ' INSERT INTO Table1 (Name,time) VALUES(''Fred'',datetime(''now''))';
begin
  FDConnection1.ExecSql(sInsertRow);
end;
```

Btw, in general it would be better to use a parameterised INSERT statement than a literal one like the above, but it's not really practical here as you are inserting the `now` value returned by Sqlite rather than the Delphi `now`
 function.

**Update: ** The code below is from a minimal project which creates your example table,
inserts a row into it and then presents it in db-aware controls (DBGrid, DBEdit) for editing.
It all works exactly as it ought to.  In particular, any changes to the row data made through
those controls are retained when tha app is next run.  Note that the SQL which creates the table specifies a primary key on the Name column/field:  this is necessary for the FDQuery1 to generate the UPDATE statements needed to save changes back to the on-disk table.

The code in the `btnSelectClick` handler shows how to set the `time` field's DisplayFormat and EditMask properties so that it only displays the time part of the stored DateTime data.

```
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit;
    btnCreateTable: TButton;
    btnInsertRow: TButton;
    btnSelect: TButton;
  [...]
  public

[...]

const
  sCreateTable = 'CREATE TABLE ''TABLE1'' (''Name'' VarChar(16) primary key, ''Time'' datetime)';
  sInsertRow = ' INSERT INTO Table1 (Name,time) VALUES(''Fred'',datetime(''now''))';
  sSelect = 'select * from table1';

procedure TForm2.btnCreateTableClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDConnection1.Connected := True;
  FDConnection1.ExecSql(sCreateTable);
end;

procedure TForm2.btnInsertRowClick(Sender: TObject);
const
begin
  FDConnection1.ExecSql(sInsertRow);
end;

procedure TForm2.btnSelectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  AField : TDateTimeField;
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := sSelect;
  FDQuery1.Open;

  //   The following shows how to  control how the time field is formatted for display
  //   in gui controls using the field's DisplayFormat
  //   and how to set up its EditMask for editing
  AField := FDQuery1.FieldByName('time') as TDateTimeField;
  AField.DisplayFormat := 'hh:nn:ss';
  AField.EditMask := '!90:00:00;1;_';
end;
end.
```

.DFM file

```
object Form2: TForm2
[...]
  object FDConnection1: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      'Database=D:\Delphi\Code\FireDAC\db1.sqlite'
      'DriverID=SQLite')
    LoginPrompt = False
  end
  object FDQuery1: TFDQuery
    Connection = FDConnection1
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    DataSet = FDQuery1
  end
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    DataSource = DataSource1
  end
  object DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator
    DataSource = DataSource1
  end
  object DBEdit1: TDBEdit
    DataField = 'Time'
    DataSource = DataSource1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is reading the database back using Delphi and FireDAC. The actual database I'm trying to read is much more complex and it's only the datetime values that my program fails to read. The SQL code I gave gives the simplest database that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please see update - this shows a completely self-contained project which includes your `time` field and works fine.  Please try it as a new project on your system.  If your own project does not work similarly, I can only think that yours has something fundamentally wrong with it.

Comment: Many thanks Martyn. Your code works but I couldn't see any real difference between yours and mine except I was generating the data externally. This led me to question the data and it seems that FireDAC will read a datetime field if it contains a datetime or a date but not a time (ie hh:nn:ss). If I change the field type in the database from datetime to string then my code works. I've mapped dtdatetime to dtwidestring but that doesn't help.  Any suggestions on how to make FireDAC read a datetime of format hh:nn:ss would be greatfully received. At least I understand what the problem is now!

Comment: I'm no expert on Sqlite, but from what I've read, it seems like internally it stores all datatypes as strings but FireDAC does a better job than most (other db-access libraries) of insulating you from this.  So it might be simplest not to try to fight it and deal with your `time` column as string data but with a restricted format - it depends, really, on what your requirements are for dealing with time formats in other locales, which your q doesn't specify.  Btw, I hope I've answered your original q and it would be good if you could accept my answer by clicking the 'tick' icon on the left.